# How to make file completion for a hidden file?

Tags: autocompletion

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> to autocomplete the file path. But the popup window won't have the dot file (hidden file, here it is the `.obsidian.vimrc` file I want to find) unless I press <kbd>.</kbd> first, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>.

I checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122136/autocomplete-hidden-files-in-vim
and added the code:

```
set wildignore-=.*
set wildignore-=*.vimrc
```

But this won't work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a custom function that adds dot-prepended files and directories *if* there is no pattern before the cursor position.

```
function! MyCompleteFileName() abort
  " match a (potential) wildcard preceding cursor position
  " NOTE: \f is a filename character, see :h 'isfname'
  let l:pattern = matchstr(strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1), '\v(\f|\*|\?)*$')
  let l:file_comp_list = getcompletion(l:pattern, "file")
  if l:pattern == ''
    let l:file_comp_list += getcompletion(".", "file")
  endif
  " let l:file_comp_list += getcompletion(l:pattern, "file_in_path")
  call complete(col('.') - len(l:pattern), l:file_comp_list)

  " must return an empty string to show the menu
  return ''
endfunction

inoremap <C-x><C-F> <C-R>=MyCompleteFileName()<CR>
```